# How to extract a frequency distribution table (histogram) in python

Tags: python, histogram, spyder, frequency-distribution

New and fresh faced in using python and first time posting here!  I have looked and cannot seem to find an answer to this one but I suspect it is an easy one....

I am using python (via Spyder interface) and have some large data sets for some data measuring Relative Humidity.  I have successfully plotted histograms however I was hoping to extract this information in table format too so that I know exactly how many counts I have for bins of 10% increments.

The bin range would be [10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100].  I have included a sample of data below to hopefully help.

To summarise in this data set, above 80% RH is bad so I would like to be able to say 1A spends less time above 80% than 2A.

Any help would be great!

| DateTime | RH_1A | RH_2A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2018 01:00 | 55.8 | 69.2 |
| 01/08/2018 02:00 | 65.8 | 79.2 |
| 01/08/2018 03:00 | 75.8 | 89.2 |
| 01/08/2018 04:00 | 85.8 | 89.2 |
| 01/08/2018 05:00 | 45.8 | 89.2 |
| 01/08/2018 06:00 | 45.8 | 49.2 |

Many thanks,

Lee

Comment: Have a look at [`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`pandas.qcut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what are you trying to get as output,
but as as suggested you can cut the data into bins using pandas.cut.

Let's say you imported the data into variable "data" as a pandas dataframe.
Then add new bins columns for respective humidities.

After that you can count the occurrences in both using simple value counts and compare the using plain logical operators. Note that you have to use "sort=False" as argument for "value_counts" so you can compare them.

```
data["RH_1A_bin"]=pd.cut(data.RH_1A,[10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100])

data["RH_2A_bin"]=pd.cut(data.RH_2A,[10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60, 70, 80, 90, 100])

data["RH_1A_bin"].value_counts(sort=False)

data["RH_2A_bin"].value_counts(sort=False)

data["RH_1A_bin"].value_counts(sort=False)>data["RH_2A_bin"].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I did get what you are trying to do so assumed you wanted to compare the number of above 85% RH occurences in each column and then compare them. If that is the case I would go like this :

```
def count_compare(col1 = RH_1A , col2 = RH_2A):
        #I do not have which format is your input having but I think you can manage to extract your columns as list 
        #col1 = [55.8,65.8,75.8,85.8,45.8,.....]
        #col2 = [69.2,79.2,89.2,89.2,89.2,49.2........]
        rh1_occurences = len([i for i in col1 if i > 85 ])
        rh2_occurences  = len([i for i in col2 if i > 85 ])
        diff = rh1_occurences-rh2_occurences
        if diff > 0 : 
            return "rh1 spends more time above RH limit "
        elif diff < 0 :
            return "rh1 spends more time above RH limit "
        else :
            return "above limit RH occurrence  is either 0 or equal in both columns "
```

Or you can compare the means which will be more representative if data inputs happened to be unbalanced.